# In Python, how can we replace all ASCII control characters in a string with black-slashes and an appoprite code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, ascii

How can we convert ASCII control characters into back-slashed escape sequences?

Before answering with something like, "just use the `repr()` function,” please read the whole question.

Suppose that we have a string containing:

- a bell character `\x07`
- a new-line character `\n`
- a backspace character `\x08`
- a carriage return `\r`

We want to convert the new-line characters into a backslash character followed by a letter n

| English Description | Input | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| replace new line with slash “n” | `chr(10)` | `chr(92) + chr(110)` |
| replace bell character with `\x07` | `chr(7)` | `chr(92) + chr(120) + chr(48) + chr(55)` |

I used to use the representation method of the string class `str.repr()` to do this kind of thing.

However, if you sanitize a string twice, redundant backslashes and quotation marks begin to appear.

```
repr(s)                          '\x07Hello\nFish\x08World\r'
repr(repr(s))                    "'\\x07Hello\\nFish\\x08World\\r'"
repr(repr(repr(s)))              '"\'\\\\x07Hello\\\\nFish\\\\x08World\\\\r\'"'
repr(repr(repr(repr(s))))        '\'"\\\'\\\\\\\\x07Hello\\\\\\\\nFish\\\\\\\\x08World\\\\\\\\r\\\'"\''
```

I require the following:

```py
def sani(s:str) -> str:
    pass # magic goes here

sani(s) == sani(sani(s))
sani(s) == sani(sani(sani(s)))
sani(s) == sani(sani(sani(sani(s))))
sani(s) == sani(sani(sani(sani(sani(s)))))
```

After we replace the control characters, future attempts to sanitize control characters should not change the string.

In general, a table of all characters we wish to convert is shown below:

```
+-----+------+
| 000 | \x00 |
+-----+------+
| 001 | \x01 |
+-----+------+
| 002 | \x02 |
+-----+------+
| 003 | \x03 |
+-----+------+
| 004 | \x04 |
+-----+------+
| 005 | \x05 |
+-----+------+
| 006 | \x06 |
+-----+------+
| 007 | \x07 |
+-----+------+
| 008 | \x08 |
+-----+------+
| 009 | \t   |
+-----+------+
| 010 | \n   |
+-----+------+
| 011 | \x0b |
+-----+------+
| 012 | \x0c |
+-----+------+
| 013 | \r   |
+-----+------+
| 014 | \x0e |
+-----+------+
| 015 | \x0f |
+-----+------+
| 016 | \x10 |
+-----+------+
| 017 | \x11 |
+-----+------+
| 018 | \x12 |
+-----+------+
| 019 | \x13 |
+-----+------+
| 020 | \x14 |
+-----+------+
| 021 | \x15 |
+-----+------+
| 022 | \x16 |
+-----+------+
| 023 | \x17 |
+-----+------+
| 024 | \x18 |
+-----+------+
| 025 | \x19 |
+-----+------+
| 026 | \x1a |
+-----+------+
| 027 | \x1b |
+-----+------+
| 028 | \x1c |
+-----+------+
| 029 | \x1d |
+-----+------+
| 030 | \x1e |
+-----+------+
| 031 | \x1f |
+-----+------+
| 127 | \x7f |
+-----+------+
| 128 | \x80 |
+-----+------+
| 129 | \x81 |
+-----+------+
| 130 | \x82 |
+-----+------+
| 131 | \x83 |
+-----+------+
| 132 | \x84 |
+-----+------+
| 133 | \x85 |
+-----+------+
| 134 | \x86 |
+-----+------+
| 135 | \x87 |
+-----+------+
| 136 | \x88 |
+-----+------+
| 137 | \x89 |
+-----+------+
| 138 | \x8a |
+-----+------+
| 139 | \x8b |
+-----+------+
| 140 | \x8c |
+-----+------+
| 141 | \x8d |
+-----+------+
| 142 | \x8e |
+-----+------+
| 143 | \x8f |
+-----+------+
| 144 | \x90 |
+-----+------+
| 145 | \x91 |
+-----+------+
| 146 | \x92 |
+-----+------+
| 147 | \x93 |
+-----+------+
| 148 | \x94 |
+-----+------+
| 149 | \x95 |
+-----+------+
| 150 | \x96 |
+-----+------+
| 151 | \x97 |
+-----+------+
| 152 | \x98 |
+-----+------+
| 153 | \x99 |
+-----+------+
| 154 | \x9a |
+-----+------+
| 155 | \x9b |
+-----+------+
| 156 | \x9c |
+-----+------+
| 157 | \x9d |
+-----+------+
| 158 | \x9e |
+-----+------+
| 159 | \x9f |
+-----+------+
| 160 | \xa0 |
+-----+------+
| 173 | \xad |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: How can you tell the difference in your sanitized string between an escape and the literal characters that correspond to it if you don't escape the escape characters themselves?

Comment: @Samwise I think we can tell the difference between an escape sequence and the literal characters which correspond to that escape sequence. A line-feed character is `chr(10)`. A back-slash followed by a letter "n" is `"".join([chr(92), chr(110)]` We can tell the different between a new-line character and backslash `n`. Under the hood we have null terminated arrays where each element in an instance of the `char` data-type in the **C** programming language. `new_line = [10, 0]` and `slash_n = [92, 110, 0]`

Comment: If I call `sani('\\n')`, how should the `sani` function know whether I wanted to "sanitize" a string that contains a backslash followed by a lowercase n (and therefore double up the backslash), or preserve the already-"sanitized" representation of a newline (and therefore not do so)?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```py
def sani(whole:str) ->str:
    result = "\\".join(repr(part)[1:-1] for part in whole.split("\\"))
    return result
```

Suppose we use the following string as a test input:

```py
test_fish = (3 * "\\").join(['\n', 'tuna', chr(7), 'anchovy', "\r", 'salmon', 'trout'])
test_fish = '\n\\\\\\tuna\\\\\\\x07\\\\\\anchovy\\\\\\\r\\\\\\salmon\\\\\\trout'
```

the output from `sani` is shown below:

```
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
```

Note that it does not matter how many times we sanitize the string to get rid of special characters.
The output will not change after the first run:

```py
for _ in range(0, 5):
    r = sani(test_fish)
    print(r)
```

```
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
\n\\\tuna\\\\x07\\\anchovy\\\\r\\\salmon\\\trout
```

Suppose that `part == "tuna"`

`repr(part)` returns something like `"\"tuna\""`

That is, `repr(part)` inserts a quotation mark at the beginning of the string and at the end of the string.

```py
fishy_string   = "mackerel"
representation = repr(fishy_string)
print(representation[0]  in "\"\'") # prints true
print(representation[-1] in "\"\'") # prints true
```

`repr(part)[1:-1]` is `repr(part)` with the first and last characters removed.

That is how we get rid of the quotation marks.

`repr()` converts a single back-slash character into two back-slashs.

The doubling of back-slashs is unwanted.

So, we will:

- get rid of backslashes.  `"a\nbc".split("\\")`
- get the representation of each piece `pieces = [repr(x) for x in ["a", "\n", "b", "c"]]`
- insert the back-slashes back into the string `"\\".join(pieces)`

We have:

```py
result = "\\".join(repr(part)[1:-1] for part in whole.split("\\")
```